# PHPPowerpoint chart with excel (Sample 8) not working

Tags: php, oop, charts, phpexcel, phppowerpoint

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPowerPoint), to create PowerPoint presentations with Charts in them using PHP. I intend to have the chart data editable (with an embed excel sheet).

I'm new to the library and still trying to figure out how exactly to go about it. The samples folder has a few helpful examples however "sample 8"(Chart with PHPExcel) does not work.

It give me the following error

```
PHPExcel has not been loaded. Include PHPExcel.php in your script, 
e.g. require_once 'PHPExcel.php'.
```

I understand it probably means I also need to install [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) and integrate it with PhpPowerpoint. But am unable to figure out how.

**Things I've tried so far**

1. Copy the contents of PhpExcel to the samples folder and `include_once 'PhpExcel.php';` in the Sample_08_Chart_with_PHPExcel.php.

This gave me the following error

`Fatal error: Class 'PhpOffice\PhpPowerpoint\Writer\PowerPoint2007\PHPExcel_Cell' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPPowerpoint_1\PHPPowerPoint-0.3.0\PHPPowerPoint-0.3.0\src\PhpPowerpoint\Writer\PowerPoint2007\Chart.php on line 938`

2. Copied the contents of PhpExcel to the 'src' folder of 'PhpPowerpoint' and `include_once 'PhpExcel.php';` on the 'PhpPowerpoint.php' file, still got the same error.
3. A few more combinations of locations and inclusions in files but it all gives me the same error.

So the questions is

1. Where should I place the PHPExcel files
2. in which file from PhpPowerpoint should I include PHPExcel.php

Answer (score 0):

Place the PHPExcel library wherever you want in your folder structure, though I'd recommend putting it in a separate subfolder at least, where you don't have any other libraries installed already... it's a separate library, so should be treated separately

You `include` PHPExcel.php in your own script, not in any of the PHPowerPoint scripts

Comment: I've tried that, if I include it in the `index.php` file of samples (which would be one of my files hypothetically) it still gives me the same error (`PHPExcel has not been loaded. Include PHPExcel.php in your script, 
e.g. require_once 'PHPExcel.php'`)

Comment: While if I include it in the `sample8.php` file of samples I get the `Fatal error: Class 'PhpOffice\PhpPowerpoint\Writer\PowerPoint2007\PHPExcel_Cell' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPPowerpoint_1\PHPPowerPoint-0.3.0\PHPPowerPoint-0.3.0\src\PhpPowerpoint\Writer\PowerPoint2007\Chart.php on line 938` error

Comment: Make sure your `include` actually points to the file `PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php` from wherever you've put the PHPExcel library

Comment: Yes it does, the fact that the error `PHPExcel has not been loaded. Include PHPExcel.php in your script, e.g. require_once 'PHPExcel.php'` does not show up when including in `Sample_08_Chart_with_PHPExcel.php` does prove that the PHPExcel class is instantiated. It's the `PhpOffice\PhpPowerpoint\Writer\PowerPoint2007\PHPExcel_Cell` that gets me confused

Comment: sorry I mean the `Fatal error: Class 'PhpOffice\PhpPowerpoint\Writer\PowerPoint2007\PHPExcel_Cell' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPPowerpoint_1\PHPPowerPoint-0.3.0\PHPPowerPoint-0.3.0\src\PhpPowerpoint\Writer\PowerPoint2007\Chart.php on line 938` error that confuses me